# 3D world coordinate to 2D image coordinate conversion

Tags: computer-vision, linear-algebra

If the camera coordinates in the world frame (x1, y1, z1) are available along with the camera attitude quaternions (or pitch roll and yaw) then how do I map a pixel (x,y) onto the camera image - given the coordinates of the pixel object (x2,y2,z2) in the world frame? I am a complete newbie into computer vision. Even a link to a relevant tutorial will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Create the view (camera) matrix

Pseudocode:

```
view = new Matrix4();
view.rotate(camRotationQuaternion);
view.translate(camX, camY, camZ);
```

#### 2. Multiply the vertex by the view matrix

Pseudocode:

```
vertexCam = view * vertexWorld;
```

#### 3. Get the `x` and `y` values of the transformed point (in camera space)

Since the point is now being "seen" from the view matrix, its `z` value represents the depth from the camera, and its `x` and `y` values represent the pixel coordinate on the flat "image" of the camera.

Pseudocode:

```
pixX = vertexCam.x;
pixY = vertexCam.y;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. If it's not too much to ask, would you mind linking a tutorial to what you wrote? I would appreciate a good understanding of the procedure

Comment: I seem to have found one at https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/computing-pixel-coordinates-of-3d-point/perspective-projection

Comment: I would look into [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/)(or [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/), it's Java port).